# Add jQuery click action on my top level menu links

Tags: jquery

I would need help with my jQuery menu script.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sentimancho/6augy27b/

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.toggle-sidebar').click(function() {
  $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
});

$('.toggle-navigation').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open').next('#site-navigation').slideToggle(300);
});

$('#site-navigation .sub-menu, #site-navigation .children').before('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>');

if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)){
  $('#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children .fa, #site-navigation .page_item_has_children .fa')
  .click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open').next('ul').slideToggle(300);
  });
} else {
  $('#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children, #site-navigation .page_item_has_children')
  .not('.current-menu-parent, .current_page_parent, .current_page_ancestor, .current-menu-ancestor')
  .hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.fa').toggleClass('open').next('ul').stop(true, true).delay(200).slideDown();
  },function() {
    $(this).children('.fa').toggleClass('open').next('ul').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp();
  });
}
});
})(jQuery);
```

I'd like to add a click action that works exactly like the hover one but I can't achieve it, after various tests (I thought it would be simple...).

The trouble in details: people in mobile devices (you can't see this on the JSFiddle) have to click exactly on the small right arrows to access the menu sublevels, it's the only way and thus it's not user-friendly.

What I'd like: if a person clicks on the menu top level (such as "Résultats" // in any place of the whole line), it shows/develops the sublevels such as "Equipe première (D2 – Groupe A)" and the 2 others.

It's exactly what hover does at this time on the JSFiddle, but I want to expand it to the click on the menu top level too (and keep both: hover + click).

Ideally, another click will hide the menu sublevels, so like a usual show/hide function on click.

PS: Of course, I can place href attributes on this menu top levels (but you should now I don't need it: no page is associated to the top levels).

**Thanks for your help!**

Bertrand

Comment: Is it an idea to check if it is a mobile viewing the page and then bind a click instead of the hover and vice versa?

Comment: Well, don't worry about that, we can add the click function to all devices, because even in a computer, I'm sure first action of many people is to click on top level labels to access sublevel ones. (I used to have "#" as href attributes, it was more evident).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add click event to top level labels.  Here's the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6augy27b/10/

```
$('#site-navigation a:not([href])').click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggleClass('open').next('ul').slideToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you lianbogo, that was really fast! One modification to submit to you: it seems to work only on mobile devices, could you please add it for all devices (see my previous comment). Other point, a question this time: pointer cursor apparition is welcome on hovering this top level labels (it will be clearer for people), do I just add links (that points to "#" for example, not very sexy) or do I deal it by adding a pointer cursor effect with CSS (even if there is no link)?

Comment: Move the code outside if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)) check, so that it works for all devices. For cursor, you can add cursor: pointer; css style to all anchor element.

Comment: OK, I just moved it outside the check and it works perfectly. Oh man, I spent so much time on this and it was so fast for you, I should have come earlier here! Thanks a lot again, for the last time :-)

Comment: Please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark if your problem is solved, thanks.

Comment: Woops, done (as you can see, it's my first steps here).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/6augy27b/14/ 
I took the fa out of the selection on line 14.

```
$('#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children, #site-navigation .page_item_has_children')
```

I changed the hover to click for this example.
Before that you should make a check which device it so you can do the hover(desktop) or the click(mobile)

Comment: Thanks to you too VRC. 2 solutions now, it's too much for me guys! :-)